# What spider is that in south of Brazil?

Tags: species-identification, taxonomy, arachnology, classification

I'd like to know if it is possible to identify the spider in the photo below.

[image: Photo]

In fact, as shown in the next picture, it is very small.

[image: Size]

**Location:** South of Brazil.

Comment: I've seen a very similar cephalothorax pattern before, but I'm not sure where. Perhaps in the Zoropsidae, but I'll have to go look through my books and get back to you.

Comment: It would help if you could see how many eyes it have. It helps a lot in spider identification.

Answer (score 2):

This is *Arachosia praesignis*, a kind of ghost spider from the Anyphaenidae family.

[image: https://inaturalist.ca/observations/150348963]

(Photo source: https://inaturalist.ca/observations/150348963 )

See this paper for representatives of both the male and female specimen of this species, plus additional species of the Arachosia genus:
https://www.biotaxa.org/Zootaxa/article/view/zootaxa.3932.1.1

(Available free on ResearchGate: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273951397_Taxonomic_revision_of_the_American_spider_genus_Arachosia_Araneae_Anyphaenidae#fullTextFileContent )

The paper reports the distribution consistent with where you found it:
[image]